# Power Query: HTTP Post Requests with Windows Authentication

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

How can you perform a **post** request using Excel's Power Query if the endpoint requires Windows Authentication?

In order to tell Power Query that my request is a Post Request, I thought I could either include a "Content" in the options, or a Method = POST header and submit the request through the **Web.Contents()** function, but Web.Contents() responds back that neither contents nor a method header are allowed unless you're using anonymous authentication.

If submitting the request using **WebAction.Request**("POST, apiUrl, options) I get an error "We haven't been given permission to perform actions against this resource". How can I give permission to access this resource?

Can Power Query really not support post requests with Windows Authentication?
If you were making a website with a C# backend, you can use Windows Authentication with post requests, and the OS and server work their magic to negotiate the user credentials. Does Excel not have this ability? It seems that post requests via Windows Auth would be a very common use case in a corporate environment.

Comment: I believe this is why different services will create a connector you can use instead of the web connector, that handles more advanced authentication methods than bearer tokens etc.